# how do i get the groups which i have joined

Tags: users, organic-groups

How can i display to my site users after joining into one group, need to display my Joined groups. suppose one person send invitation to his friend and he has joined in to his group after click link. then he has to see in his friend group he has joined using Views.

Like: 
      My Joined Groups
      XXXXXXGroup

Thanks

Comment: I have created something similar but using code, you interested?

Comment: yes Saadlulu, Please share with me and process to execute.....

Comment: Just let me make sure that this is what you want, you want: after inviting your friend to a group to see in his profile that he joined the group using your link? or just get all the users in a group

Comment: To see in his profile that he joined the group using your link and he never invite anyone into this group. he can able to join into friends group after request and he should not invite others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a view that comes with OG 7.x-1.x (I'm using 7.x-1.4) that displays all of the groups subscribed to. If you have views running, you could  simply append /user-groups to your url and you should see it. After that, you can go into the view and modify it to meet your specific needs (e.g., make a block or whatever).